Fix Got invalid task translation, currently only ('text2text-generation', 'text-generation', 'summarization') are supported
How to fix the Got invalid task translation, currently only ('text2text-generation', 'text-generation', 'summarization') are supported (type=value_error) error thrown from following code:
from config import set_environment
from langchain import HuggingFaceHub, PromptTemplate, LLMChain

set_environment()

customer_email = """
I hope this email finds you amidst an aura of understanding, despite the tangled mess of emotions swirling within me as 
I write to you. I am writing to pour my heart out about the recent unfortunate experience I had with one of your coffee 
machines that arrived ominously broken, evoking a profound sense of disbelief and despair.

To set the scene, let me paint you a picture of the moment I anxiously unwrapped the box containing my highly 
anticipated coffee machine. The blatant excitement coursing through my veins could rival the vigorous flow of coffee 
through its finest espresso artistry. However, what I discovered within broke not only my spirit but also any semblance 
of confidence I had placed in your esteemed brand.

Imagine, if you can, the utter shock and disbelief that took hold of me as I laid eyes on a disheveled and mangled 
coffee machine. Its once elegant exterior was marred by the scars of travel, resembling a war-torn soldier who had 
fought valiantly on the fields of some espresso battlefield. This heartbreaking display of negligence shattered my 
dreams of indulging in daily coffee perfection, leaving me emotionally distraught and inconsolable
"""

summary_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template="""Summarize this: {complaint}""", input_variables=["complaint"])
model_id = "google-t5/t5-base"

summarizer_llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id=model_id, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "max_length": 180})
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=summary_prompt_template, llm=summarizer_ll

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/O60774/ws/gen-ai/aravind/ch3/error.py", line 25, in <module>
    summarizer_llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id=model_id, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "max_length": 180})
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/O60774/ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/load/serializable.py", line 75, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/O60774/ws/gen-ai/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 341, in __init__
    raise validation_error
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for HuggingFaceHub
__root__
  Got invalid task translation, currently only ('text2text-generation', 'text-generation', 'summarization') are supported (type=value_error)

